# SharePoint returns General Exception: An unspecified error has occurred

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

We create a Team with Power Automate using the Graph API from an HTTP Action:

[image: Screenshot from Flow]

We are calling the following URI using application permissions.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups('8c250cdd-1f21-405d-b45f-f95cf248e9d8')/sites('root')/webUrl
```

But the result is an `HTTP 500`:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "generalException",
    "message": "An unspecified error has occurred.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "0649718d-057d-4c4c-9fec-986c158376ee",
      "date": "2019-12-02T09:11:10"
    }
  }
}
```

Calling the same URL in Graph Explorer works as expected.

Comment: What do you get if you exclude the `webUrl` from the URI?

Comment: We are checking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a custom connector instead of an HTTP action.