# Issue with fetching site info of a microsoft teams group

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to fetch the site info of a Microsoft teams group using c# API. I had written this code sometime in November and it was working fine then. But now the call fails with a status code of 500 and Internal server error.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient;
/// ...
Site siteInfo = graphClient
    .Groups["groupId"]
    .Sites["root"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync()
    .GetAwaiter()
    .GetResult();
```

When I try the following GET request `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{GroupId}/sites/root` using Postman I get the below error,

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "generalException",
    "message": "An unspecified error has occurred.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5c969a0e-aeca-451d-a832-6d538e278773",
      "date": "2020-01-03T10:56:22"
    }
  }
}
```

This request used to work previously from Postman but it stopped working. I checked the app permissions and they are fine and have remained unchanged since they were working earlier. However, this request works fine with Graph Explorer.

I see the same issue mentioned in [SharePoint returns General Exception: An unspecified error has occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139666/sharepoint-returns-general-exception-an-unspecified-error-has-occurred) but I don't think the solution they have mentioned would help me here.

Comment: Do you have required permissions for the API call?

Comment: Yes. I have given the following "Application" permissions to the app - Sites.FullControl.All, Sites.Manage.All, 
Sites.Read.All and 
Sites.ReadWrite.All

Comment: Could you please try to pass {site id} instead of root?

Comment: it looks like you're requesting the sites for the group with an id of "groupId", as in a literal string not a variable named groupId. Could just be a simple typo?